# Create a CurrentValueSubject from another CurrentValueSubject

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have a `CurrentValueSubject` in an object and I want another `CurrentValueSubject` to copy the changes of the first one.

I can't find a way of easily doing that without having to do something like this:

```
subjectA.assign(to: \.value, on: subjectB).store(in: &cancelables)
```

It would be nice to be able to initialize the `subjectB` using `subjectA`. Is there a way of doing something like that?

Edit:
For example I was thinking it would be great to be able to do something like:

```
let subjectB = CurrentValueSubject(from: subjectA)
```

Comment: Hi, Andres: can you explain what you mean by "initialize the subjectB using subjectA"? If they are always to be the same, why do you need two different Subjects? What is the use case here? Thanks

Comment: Thanks @matt. It's the same value but it comes from a different layer. In the place where I'm going to use it has a different "meaning"...

Comment: Hmmm, but you do realize that multiple subscribers can subscribe to the same CurrentValueSubject, right? So who cares what the meaning is? Each pipeline that subscribes can do whatever it wants with the value as it comes along.

Comment: Or, if you really need this in two different places, then just make the second one a pipeline that subscribes to the first one and passes the value along.

Comment: yes, I'm aware of that. But this is more an encapsulation problem. I don't want/can't expose "the original" source. It needs to go thought a second `CurrentValueSubject`.

Comment: Why does it "needs to go thought a second CurrentValueSubject"? You can say it needs to go through a second _publisher_, but you should not be exposing its type; all publishers should be typed as AnyPublisher anyway. That is why I say a subscribing pipeline would do.

Comment: Googling in that direction! Thanks!!!

Comment: is the second publisher an exact replica of the first (as far as values emitted are concerned), or would it emit all the values of the first, plus potentially its own values?

Comment: @NewDev The point of my answer is that even if the second one _does_ do something in addition, it can. It can all go into the publisher, i.e. the pipeline head, that is the second  one.

Comment: @matt, I wanted to see if the OP had a more complicated requirement that might not be satisfied by replicating `pub1` as in your answer. Maybe I didn't fully understand your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just have the second publisher be a subscriber to the first publisher. Example:

```
let pub1 = CurrentValueSubject<String,Never>("howdy")
lazy var pub2 : AnyPublisher<String,Never> = {
    self.pub1.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}()
```

Example of usage:

```
    pub1.sink {print($0)}.store(in: &storage)
    pub2.sink {print($0)}.store(in: &storage)
    delay(1) {
        self.pub1.send("hey")
        delay(2) {
            self.pub1.send("ho")
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
howdy
howdy
[delay]
hey
hey
[delay]
ho
ho
```

So both publishers are giving out the same value, which seems to be what you want.